# Convert generic parameter of type T to List<TP> when T is IEnumerable<TP>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, linq-to-objects

My application has a method that caches a value. I need a second method that check if the generic parameter of type T implements IEnumerable and not implements IList. If the answer is yes, the method should do a .ToList and cast it back to T (See comment in code example).

**Can you tell me how I do the .ToList() to return a List casted to back to T?** (Is it actually possible?)

Something like this:

```
public T ToListIfIEnumerable<T>(T value)
{
    var needToCovert = TypeImplementsGenericIEnumerableButNotGenericIList(value);

    if (!needToCovert)
    {
        return value;
    }

    // return value.ToList() <-- How to do that???
}

private bool TypeImplementsGenericIEnumerableButNotGenericIList<T>(T value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();

    var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
    var gi = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
    var gl = typeof(IList<>);

    // It would be better if the next lines did't compare strings!
    // Suggestions welcome...
    var implementsIEnumerable = interfaces.Any(
        i => i.IsGenericType && i.Name == gi.Name && i.Namespace == gi.Namespace);
    var implementsIList = interfaces.Any(
        i => i.IsGenericType && i.Name == gl.Name && i.Namespace == gl.Namespace);

    return implementsIEnumerable && !implementsIList;
}
```

Backgrond info:
The object that uses the method does something like Lazy. Caching an IEnumerable makes not much sense in examples like: `Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid())` It does gives new Guid's every time you call it. That is why I would like to do a ToList().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic typing and overloading could help here, if you don't mind using `dynamic`:

```
object ConvertToListIfNecessary(dynamic input)
{
    return MaybeToList(input);
}

private IList<T> MaybeToList<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    return input.ToList();
}

private IList<T> MaybeToList<T>(IList<T> input)
{
    return input;
}

private object MaybeToList(object input)
{
    // Take whatever action you want if the input *doesn't* implement
    // IEnumerable<T>
}
```

Basically this gets the smarts behind `dynamic` to do the grungy reflection work for you. It  may not be quite as quick as something that's hand-rolled, but it's likely to be *much* simpler to get right.

Comment: Thanks, that does what I want! I don't like the Dynmic stuff that much but I do that in private methods it is not visible in other classes and then  I don't care much. It saves me a lot of reflection. Thanks!